# Connecting bluetooth devices with React-Native App

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I am using react-native-bluetooth-serial. I get this error whenever I try to connect a bluetooth device via my react native app:

Error: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
Unable to connect to device

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
 connectToDevice () {
    if (this.state.discovering) {
      return false
    } else {
      this.setState({ discovering: true })
      console.log("searching");
      BluetoothSerial.list()
      .then((Devices) => {
        this.setState({ Devices, discovering: false })
        for(var i = 0; 1; i++)
        {
          if(Devices[i]["name"] == "JBL Flip 3 SE")
          {
            console.log(Devices[i]["id"]);
            BluetoothSerial.connect(Devices[i]["id"]).then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            })
            break;
          }
        }
        // console.log(unpairedDevices);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
    }
}
```

Same happens even when I clone the example repository.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) for bluetooth in React Native and if you need live example you can check out our side project which uses this lib to send colors to Arduino and handle LED lights https://github.com/SparingSoftware/HomeLed

Comment: Will bluetooth classic also work for this library?

Comment: @ShreyaB: No, according to the README "It does NOT support: bluetooth classic devices."